# Adding Child Element to your Customize Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, panel, controltemplate

I am making a customized panel in which I can add any and many elements as I can, but I want to add child elements dynamically from main.xaml ,I am not even able to access that panel in main.xaml why is it so ??
I am making use of custom template in making my customize Panel.

`Library.cs`

```
class Modal_Main : Window
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    Grid gr = new Grid();
    public Modal_main()
    {


        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        this.AllowsTransparency = true;
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        this.Background = Brushes.Black;
        this.Opacity = 0.5;
        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.AddChild(gr);
        rect.Margin = new Thickness(350, 100, 350, 100);
        rect.Fill = Brushes.White;
        rect.RadiusX = 5;
        rect.RadiusY = 5;
        rect.Name = "rectangle";
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += Modal_main_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        gr.Children.Add(rect);
        this.Show();

    }
    private void Modal_main_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(this.rect.IsMouseOver == false)
           this.Close();
    }
```

I want to use this panel something like this in `Main.xaml`.So that when I add a child element inside Model_Main then that change is directly reflected in my Modal_Main class
`Main.xaml`

```
    <my_namespace:Modal_Main >

           <Button> My_test_button </Button>
           <!--I want this button element to appear in my Modal_Main class when i add this child elements here -->

    </my_namespace:Modal_Main>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @AymenDaoudi I have edited my question ..plz have a look..

Comment: Are you want add many controls such that button at run-time?

Comment: @AliAdl yeah... I want to add any control that I add from `Main.xaml` to get reflected in my `Modal_Main.cs` file

Comment: are you adding at runtime? or in Xaml file?

Comment: what i get is that you want to access to a control from .cs file that is inserted in xaml file? am i true?

Comment: @AliAdl In `Xaml file`

Comment: @AliAdl Actually i am creating a new Window on some button click and i want to add controls to that new window from `Main.xaml` file so that I can access it from my .cs file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create your own custom template for your window. We do this via `ControlTemplate` of the Window. so set the style of window to blow:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
            <Setter Property="Template"> 
                <Setter.Value> 
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
                        <Grid> 
                                    <!-- Actual Window Content --> 
                                    <AdornerDecorator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"> 
                                        <ContentPresenter /> 
                                    </AdornerDecorator> 
                                </DockPanel> 
                        </Grid> 
                    </ControlTemplate> 
                </Setter.Value> 
            </Setter> 
            </Style> 
       </Window.Style>
    <Grid>
       /// any childs you want to add in your window's content.
    <Grid>
```

and a complete sample:

```
                                <!-- Title bar separator--> 
                                <Border Height="1" 
                                        DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                        Background="{DynamicResource 
                    MainWindowTitleBarSeparator}" />

                                <!-- Actual Window Content --> 
                                <AdornerDecorator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"> 
                                    <ContentPresenter /> 
                                </AdornerDecorator> 
                            </DockPanel> 
                        </Border> 
                    </Grid> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource Self}, Path=Maximized}" 
                                     Value="False"> 
                            <Setter TargetName="MaximizeRestoreImage" 
                                    Property="Source" 
                                    Value="/MixModes.Synergy.Resources;
                component/Resources/Maximize.png" /> 
                        </DataTrigger> 
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                </ControlTemplate> 
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter> 
     </Style> 
   </Window.Style>

<Grid>
   /// any childs you want to add in your window's content.
<Grid>

</Window>
```

also you can define the `Style` with `x:Key="MyWindowCustomTemplate"` in a seperate `ResourceDictionary` file, then set the `Window`'s `Style` property to `{StaticResource Key=MyWindowCustomTemplate}`.

Comment: Dis is not what i am looking for...actually I want to create something like this interface http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals .So that a model appear over my MainWindow on some button click .

Comment: In my  `Modal_Main.cs` file  I have instantiated a `Window` with `Grid` as its child Element. Now what i really want is when I add some controls from `Main.xaml` file that control should appear as a child element of `Grid Panel` and not of Window..Is there some way to implement that?

Comment: then you want to create a custom template to your window, true?

Comment: yeah i want to create a custom template to my window